# Read from text file and count the number of integers using sizeof results to nan

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code to count the number of integers read from a text file, sizeof function is displaying "nan".

```
double getSamplesize(vector<double> data)
{
    int samplesize;
    samplesize=sizeof(data);
    cout<<samplesize<< endl;

}
```

on the int(main):

```
cout<<"sample size: " << getsamplesize(arr) << endl;
```

Expected output should be: sample size: (number)
But im getting

(number)
sample size: nan

Comment: You are not returning anything from that function.  Also `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does.  And why is the return type `double` instead of an integer type?

Comment: Did you mean `samplesize = data.size();`? And then return `samplesize` (changing the type of `getSamplesize` from `double` to `size_t`)?

Comment: I tried `int`  and the numbers were way off. `sizeof` got me what I wanted but it had the nan which I want to get rid of.

Comment: `size_t` did the same as `int` and replaced nan with a large number.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @LORENZOGABRIELCABALLA If you want the number of entries, you want `size()`, not `sizeof()`

Comment: sizeof() gives you the size in bytes in memory of the item being passed in. Doesn't give you the size in terms of the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> double getSamplesize(vector<double> data)
> ^^^^^^
> ```

You've declared that the function returns `double`. But your function does not end in a `return` statement. As a result, the behaviour of the program is undefined, and that undefined behaviour is what you observe.

> ```
> sizeof(data)
> ```

This returns the size of the type of the variable. It is completely unrelated to the number of elements, or the size of the array owned by the vector.

> Expected output should be: sample size: (number) But im getting

The first piece of code in your program that streams into standard output is this line:

> ```
> cout<<samplesize<< endl;
> ```

Thus the expected output cannot possibly begin with "sample size:".